# Sorting the data in a cell in GoogleSpreadsheets to extract just one component

Tags: sql, excel, google-apps-script

I am using this ImportRange formula to call information from one column of a spreadsheet into a different google spreadsheet.

=FILTER(ImportRange("key","onfleet_export!U:U"), ImportRange("key","onfleet_export!AE:AE")>=DATEVALUE(C2), ImportRange("key","onfleet_export!AE:AE")<=DATEVALUE(C3+2))

That formula works fine. My problem arises when I look at the data in the cell. I want to find a formula that will pull only one part of the old cell's contents into the new spreadsheet's cell.

Each cell in my old spreadsheet looks something like this: 
url / 12PM - 4PM / Condition: 85 / elevator / Product Notes:

The only part that I want to have in my new spreadsheet is the 12PM - 4PM part. The times can be 7AM-12PM, 12PM-4PM, and 4PM-8PM- but there are a few exceptions to this rule.

I would really appreciate any suggestions that you can provide. I was thinking of using the QUERY formula, but can't seem to find any guides on how to implement this.

Thank you!

Comment: Are the values always in the same order and separated by a slash?

Comment: Yes @AuriellePerlmann

Comment: Can you share a sample sheet with a small import range - I have an answer for you but need to test first

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataAsList = cellData.split('/');
var desiredData = dataAsList[1];
```

If your date is always in the same place, this is easy, (even if it isn't the prettiest).

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do it without using the google apps script, and instead using a formula?